# Provide DynamoDB table name in AWS CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS, so this might be a simple question.

When I create a DynamoDB table using AWS CloudFormation template, I do not see a way to provide a name for the table. So in the end it is named something like `{stackName}-{resourceName}-{randomLetters}`. However, if I create DynamoDB table manually, I have a possibility to provide a table name.

My template:

```
  "Resources" : {
    "mytable" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties" : {
        "KeySchema" : {
          "HashKeyElement": {
            "AttributeName" : {"Ref" : "HashKeyElementName"},
            "AttributeType" : {"Ref" : "HashKeyElementType"}
          }
        },
        "ProvisionedThroughput" : {
          "ReadCapacityUnits" : {"Ref" : "ReadCapacityUnits"},
          "WriteCapacityUnits" : {"Ref" : "WriteCapacityUnits"}
        }                              
      }
    }
    ...
  }
```

For instance, if I create a stack called "mystack", created DynamoDB table would have a name similar to "mystack-mytable-NUEXAXXOMBXX".

Comment: By "AWS template", you mean _Amazon CloudFormation_. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can give your table a name by using the "Tablename" property. Here's the link to the docs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html

```
"Resources" : {
  "mytable" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties" : {
      "KeySchema" : {
        "HashKeyElement": {
          "AttributeName" : {"Ref" : "HashKeyElementName"},
          "AttributeType" : {"Ref" : "HashKeyElementType"}
        }
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput" : {
        "ReadCapacityUnits" : {"Ref" : "ReadCapacityUnits"},
        "WriteCapacityUnits" : {"Ref" : "WriteCapacityUnits"}
      },
      "TableName": "MyDynamoDBTableName"                       
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can name it, **provided you never try to make modifications**. That means no schema or throughput changes.

Comment: @tedder42 How is this useful then?  I want to use CloudFormation to update my throughput, you're saying that's not possible?  Of course I want a specific table name, in my case it's "Beta.Foo.Bar"

Comment: @jhilden look for "Update requires: Replacement" in the docs. Those are ones you can't do if you fix a name. You can change throughput but not schemas or indexes.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't able to give your table a name. You'll need to capture this after it is created and use it inside your application